# Save a file from server using flash

Tags: actionscript, flash

I have added a button in flash I want this button to save a mp3 file from the server when a user clicks on it inside a browser.

One way to do this is:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var fileReference:FileReference = new FileReference();

var data:ByteArray; // load up your data into this ByteArray

fileReference.save(data, "outputfile.dat");
```

But how do we load a mp3 file from server in variable 'data'?

Comment: You say "from the server", but to you actually want to upload the file TO the server? If you are simply talking about allowing the user to download a file, just make the browser navigate to the file's URL using navigateToURL().

Comment: I just want when someone clicks on a button inside flash, he is able to download a file from the server on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just found FileReference.download() on google